# MySQL help needed - Add questions/answers in the fewest queries possible?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm writing a very simple PHP script for surveys. At this time, it can only handle one survey at a time. The database schema looks like this:

```
table 1: questions
    primary key: question_id
    second field: question
table 2: answers
    primary key: answer_id
    second field: answer
    foreign key: question_id
```

I have an admin section in this script that allows me to add one question at a time. I've also made it possible to add a variable number of answers to each question. I'm having trouble with two things:

1. How can I make sure that the variable number of answers being added all have foreign keys that link to the correct question? Do I need to `INSERT` the question, then `SELECT` it to find its ID, then `INSERT` the answers? I feel like there should be a better way to do it.
2. What's the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Is my database schema trash? Do I need a bunch of queries to get what I want done? I'm not fluent in SQL :/

Thanks!

Gerard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to insert the question. Then you can use `$questionId = mysql_insert_id();`, this gives you the generated id of the last insert. Now you can use that to insert your answers properly.

Answer (score 1):

your database schema is good and three queries are all right. Although you can use an API function instead of second query but it's doesn't really make any difference. 
Note that you shouldn't select your question anyway, but special mysql function called LAST_INSERT_ID();

the only thing you forgot is a field to mark right answer/answer points or whatever of the kind